# Eliminate header information from multiple text files

Tags: python, r, header, file-import

I have multiple text files (more than 500 files). Each file starts with header information that I don't need and would like to eliminate from the file. The header information ends at line 33 for all the files. What is best way/tool to conduct such task?

I have access to R and I can get access to python if necessary. I provided an image below as one example of those files. (I would like to get rid of the information prior to ~A)

I appreciate you help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Try using the readLines function, read in the file, remove the first 33 line and then writeLines back to the file.

Comment: Can you paste the example header in your question as formatted text, rather than as an image?

Comment: 'Eliminate' suggests you want to actively edit all the files to remove the header, but 'skip' means you only want to ignore it in file-import. If you did want to programmatically eliminate it, you could use also PERL or awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

filename = 'foo.txt'
temp_filename = 'foo.temp.txt'

with open(filename) as f:
    # skip 32 lines:
    for n in range(32):
        f.readline()
    # write data from line 33 and next lines to a new file
    with open(temp_filename, 'w') as w:
        w.writelines(f)

# delete original file and rename the temp file so it replaces the original
os.remove(filename)
os.rename(temp_filename, filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

[pandas `read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has a `skiprows` parameter:

```
pd.read_csv('foo.txt', skiprows=33)
```

or, using a context-handler:

```
with pd.read_csv('foo.txt', skiprows=33) as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

R's `read.table` has a skip parameter. That "~A" at the beginning of the header line, however, would require special handling. I think I would probably leave it out as well and then assign the column names to be as you desire.

```
 filename <- "sthng.txt"
 my_df <- read.table( filename, header = FALSE, 
                                colnames=c("DET", "hello", "Variable"),
                                skip = 34)
```